# Vaadin-server 8.16.0 Runtime Dependency com.sun.jna

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

After upgrading Vaadin server to 8.16.0, I get this runtime error during the app starting up time.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;

    at com.sun.jna.platform.mac.IOKit.<clinit>(IOKit.java:51) ~[jna-platform-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0 (b0)]

    at com.sun.jna.platform.mac.IOKitUtil.<clinit>(IOKitUtil.java:39) ~[jna-platform-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0 (b0)]

    at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacComputerSystem.platformExpert(MacComputerSystem.java:87) ~[oshi-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]

    at oshi.util.Memoizer$1.get(Memoizer.java:87) ~[oshi-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]

    at oshi.hardware.platform.mac.MacComputerSystem.getHardwareUUID(MacComputerSystem.java:69) ~[oshi-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]

    at com.vaadin.pro.licensechecker.MachineId.getComputerId(MachineId.java:23) ~[vaadin-server-8.16.0.jar:8.16.0]
```

It seems that the com.sun.jna isn't the same version required for Vaadin. I have a look at the document "pom.xml configuration for Vaadin 8" on Vaadin website but don't see how the com.sun.jna is included.

What is missing?

Comment: And this is specific to 8.16?  Other versions don't show this problem? What does a dependency report from maven show where it comes from and which versions are conflicting?

Comment: It is most likely duplicate JNA dependency. Vaadin 8.16.0 is under commercial license and our license checker uses these dependencies.

Comment: Thanks both for your information. I will roll back the version.